# How to show couple images in preview of ANTD carousel

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd, jcarousel, ant-design-pro

I was wondering is it possible to show couple images on single preview of ANTD carousel.
For insrance i have a carousel on which i may have different amount of immages.
The problem is that i want to show all avaliable images in preview without heving to schroll through them.
I tried to change size of immages but that didn't help.
Also i haven't found any properties in ANTD for that.
Does anyone know is it possible?

```
import { Carousel } from 'antd';

const contentStyle = {
  height: '160px',
  color: '#fff',
  lineHeight: '160px',
  textAlign: 'center',
  background: '#364d79',
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Carousel effect="fade">
    <div>
      <h3 style={contentStyle}>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3 style={contentStyle}>2</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3 style={contentStyle}>3</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3 style={contentStyle}>4</h3>
    </div>
  </Carousel>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Comment: I just tried adding a div around 1-2 and 3-4. Please refer: https://react-id24e5.stackblitz.io/
Is this what you wanted to implement with dynamic images-per-page value?

Comment: Or do you want 1st slide to show all the images as a preview, then followed by sliding through individual images?

Comment: Yes i need a second option. I want 1st slide to show all images as a preview,  
I tried to use ANTD Image.PreviewGroup for that also but i don't know what will happen if someone will upload 5-8 pictures. My div container probably will colapse.

Comment: Are you looking to show a thumbnail in the first frame of your carousel that has all the available images? the `Image.PreviewGroup` is for image modals and your example has text. have a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bh3v4k?file=src/App.js) and tell me if this is close

Comment: 4UmNinja, yes this exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: updated with answer. would love the thumbs up or suggestions on improving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bh3v4k?file=src/App.js) what seemed to work.

Mainly just added an extra item to my array in 0th position and conditionally rendered a preview frame which included all the images in a grid.

Sample:

```js
const images = [...new Array(5).keys()].map((rowIndex, _, array) => {

  if (rowIndex === 0) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div key={rowIndex} style={previewStyle}>
          {array.map((colIndex) => (
            <h3 key={(rowIndex + 1) * (colIndex + 1)} style={h3Style}>
              Preview: {colIndex}
            </h3>
          ))}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h3 key={rowIndex} style={{...h3Style, lineHeight: '160px',}}>
        {rowIndex}
      </h3>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you 4UmNinja, that very helped me